# Business proposal

Tags: business-language

A business proposal is when a company offers a service to a client.

What is it called when a client instead writes an offer to various companies using the same or similar format of a business proposal template?

Comment: When you explain why that offer is not a business proposal, we can help. Is the client shopping for services from businesses, like an RFP (request for proposal)?

Comment: What kind of client offer are you referring to? What is the content of the client document. In my business, we get a *Request for Proposal*, which of course initiates the *Proposal* response.

Comment: As mentioned its content is similar of a business proposal, description of my company, description of tasks, milestones which I decide the initial price on, deadlines...

Comment: That sounds like a *project specification*, which may be included in an RFP.